# How to create and print a string array by given inputs in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string, input, scanf

I just started to learn C and I have some issues about taking inputs and how to use them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int test_case;
    scanf("%d\n",&test_case);
    char arr[test_case][test_case];

    //here, I tried to place values into array
    for (int i = 0; i < test_case; i++) {
        scanf("%s\n",&arr[i]);
    }

    //and print
    for (int j = 0; j < test_case; j++)
        printf("Case #%d %s\n", j+1, arr[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, as you can see, firstly, I took the test_case value and with that size I created an array (arr). But placing didn't go with way that I wanted. This was the result.

```
3 ->test_case
123 -> 1st element
789 -> 2nd
456 -> 3rd
results
Case #1 123789456
Case #2 789456
Case #3 456

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 10.155 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Case #1 should've 123, case #2 = 789 but I couldn't do it. The question is how can I do that?

Comment: You do know that a string of `x` characters needs `x + 1` elements to fit the null-terminator? If you give the input `3` for `test_case` then you only have space for two characters in the strings. Are you really sure that you want the size of each string to be `test_case - 1`?

Comment: Think about the memory layout of a 2 dimensional array.  How does that get built in the stack?

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. I really thank both of you! Problem fixed.

Comment: But also, may I ask something. I understood that my mistake was setting the size of each string to test_case - 1. But  when the size was test_case - 1, how case #1 stored 9 chars (123789456)? I mean, shouldn't I have get an error?

Comment: `scanf("%s\n",&arr[i]);` is bad as it lacks a width  limitation.  This code ended up writing outside the bounds of `arr[i]`.

Comment: "I mean, shouldn't I have get an error? " --> do not expect C to catch your errors.  Its like riding a bike _without_ training wheels.

Comment: Cool! Cool, cool, cool :)

Comment: C has no kind of bounds checking, it's up to you and your program to make sure that you don't go out of bounds. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score -1):

i don't really know what's wrong with your code. Except that you don't need '\n' inside of your scanf

```
scanf("%d",test_case);
```

Although here you go a simple way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int test_case;
    scanf("%d",&test_case);
    char **arr;
    arr= malloc(test_case*sizeof(char));

    //here, I tried to place values into array
    for (int i = 0; i < test_case; i++) {
        arr[i]=malloc(test_case*sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s",arr[i]);
    }
    //and print
    for (int j = 0; j < test_case; j++)
        printf("Case #%d %s\n", j+1, arr[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope i helped!

Have a great day!